# How to apply an interval/ delay to a for loop in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to begin my scene with a random number from 1-3 being generated in a for loop.

I intend for the number to be random each time, however i don't wan't the same two numbers to be generated directly after each other, instead firstly generating a random number between 1-3, then waiting 60 seconds, generating a random number between 1-3 excluding the most recently generated number.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KOTH_ZoneRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Rand;
    int Lenght = 4;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    void Start()
    {
        list = new List<int>(new int[Lenght]);

        for (int j = 1; j < Lenght; j++)
        {

            Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);

            while (list.Contains(Rand))
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
            }

            list[j] = Rand;
            print(list[j]);
        }

    }
}
```

*Edit* attempted to implement a co-routine to act as an interval for the loop. however it's still not working, its prints to the console so the co-routine is definitely being executed, however the WaitForSeconds function doesn't seem to be working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KOTH_ZoneRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Rand;
    int Length = 4;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    void Start()
    {
        list = new List<int>(new int[Length]);

        for (int j = 1; j < Length; j++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(loopDelay());
            Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);

            while (list.Contains(Rand))
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
            }

            list[j] = Rand;
            print(list[j]);
        }

    }
    IEnumerator loopDelay ()
    {

        print("started delay");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two options, coroutine or polling. Can you explain how you're going to use this value? Is it always exactly 60 seconds when it changes? Do you want this sequence to continue forever?

Comment: The game itself is essentially a King of The Hill style first person shooter, i want to use the random value to randomise the movement pattern of the Score Hill. yes if possible continuing the sequence forever would be preferable, thanks so much for the reply

Comment: Also the first iteration of the RGN would then be responsible for the first location of the Score hill

Comment: StartCoroutine is non-blocking and pushes the called function into a pseudo-parallel execution, which is why you're not seeing the expected delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start method can be a coroutine, so change return type to `IEnumerator`.
2. Add `yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);` at the end of for loop.

```cs
IEnumerator Start()
{
    list = new List<int>(new int[Lenght]);

    for (int j = 1; j < Lenght; j++)
    {
        Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);

        while (list.Contains(Rand))
        {
            Rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
        }

        list[j] = Rand;
        print(list[j]);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: but it is nicer to have the start function call a coroutine as Immersive suggests bellow. The coroutine would then just contain the code your Start function contains

Comment: Sorry I can't agree with you, I think discard a builtin feature to gild the lily is not nicer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer anyway because it's good ;)
i agree with you that for doing ONLY this it's fine to use the built in functionality. I'm just used to bigger projects, and your start function might call multiple coroutines, with different time intervals for example. But you're right that when coding, one should count 1,2, many. And calling an external iEnumerator from within the start function is only nicer when it's really needed.

Comment: I always forget that `start` can be a coroutine in its own right.  I still prefer not to use it this way as to me it feels non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
void start() {
    StartCoroutine(KothTimer());
}

IEnumerator KothTimer() {

    var wait = new WaitForSeconds(HillSwitchDelay);

    while(enabled) {
        var chosenHill = ListOfHills[Random.Range(0, ListOfHills.count)];
        SetActiveHill(chosenHill);
        yield return wait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on shingo's answer here from a performance standpoint (I don't like this while loop, because even though it will eventually end, it is only probabilistically bound to a worst-case scenario ^^. ofc it works, it's just ugly):

```
using System.Linq;

void start()
{
    StartCoroutine(KothTimer());
}

IEnumerator KothTimer()
{
    System.Random rnd= new System.Random();
    var oneToFourShuffled = (new int[4]{1,2,3,4}).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < Length; j++)
    {
        list[j] = oneToFourShuffled[j];
        print(list[j]);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
    }
}
```